# displaying custom fields (profile) in a view

Tags: profile, ibm-connections

I have added some custom fields to the profiles in connections. Now I would like to create an overview (a view or list) and display the values.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive article on the Wiki
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Customizing_IBM_Connections_4.0_Profiles

> "This article has provided an end-to-end scenario illustrating the new
>   customization techniques in the IBM Connections 4.0 Profiles
>   component. The reader was able to define new extension fields to
>   associate with their users, so as to meet a typical business scenario,
>   and provide a tailored presentation of the users in the social network
>   to encourage use of the data."

it's for version 4.0, and should broadly apply to 5.0.

To continue the answer... you'll want to use the ext attributes in the search for profiles 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Searching_Profiles_programmatically_ic50&content=apicontent

and call GET /profiles/atom/search.do?FIELD_EXTATTR_SCHOOL=Westford 
where school is your new attribute name

Comment: the wiki document doesn't cover my question. I want to create an overview (list) of profiles sorted by the custom fields e.g. by employment date, by birthday. How to create such a list is not covered. I assume the way would be to create a html page/snippet and create the list via the Connections API?

Comment: added an update per your comment... you'll need to use the API